# jKey (JavaScript key shortcut plugin) Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, keyboard-shortcuts, jkey

Me and a friend are writing a plugin for jQuery that makes it easy for devs to add key shortcuts and we're damn close but no cigar. We're having issues with the key combos. It seems like we are having issues when you call the same selector multiple times on a page.

Try pressing alt+a... youll see it works one time, then gets all mangled up. Anyone know how to fix it? It'll be on github after it's corrected and I'd be happy to add "thank you to" link to whoever can fix this in the header with the copyright info :)

It's nicely documented and i have all the code and stuff here. So... anyone?

http://jsbin.com/azaha4

-- UPDATE --

Has been fixed and it's now on:

Github:
http://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey

Full Documentation:
http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey/

Comment: Oops, sorry, im mega tired, i fixed it. It was supposed to be key shortcuts. I believe the link is a better description of the script.

Comment: You seem to be using a lot of "for ... in" loops - that scares me because those are inherently fragile ... however a quick scan over the code suggests that you're not completely insane, so I need to look at it somewhat more closely

Comment: Any suggestions? Originally way back when I had the idea i posted tips on how i should end up building this and only 1 person responded and that person said doing key combos like this is "impossible" so we've being hacking on it for some time :\ and in the process probably muddied it up

Comment: I suggest using `[]` for a new array, rather than `Array()` - that's just a random note

Comment: Thanks. Changed it, nothing seems to be changed though.

Comment: No I didn't expect it would fix things :-)  One thing that sticks out to me is that when I do the demo page, if I click "a" and then (after the "a" popup is dismissed) I press the "alt" key, I immediately get the popup for "you pressed alt+a" which is incorrect. It's like the "keyup" handler for the "a" doesn't really work; maybe the key code isn't there in the event the way the code expects it to be.

Comment: Yeah. I might be just too tired or something. My friend (@sebnitu) and I wrote this, we had it working, but then we added a key return (be able to return the key that was pressed) and it's all messed up. Just wanted to get it up tonight or tomorrow for a demo. Damn. Thanks tho, ill keep looking.

Comment: @Oscar remove the alerts from your callbacks and you seem to have a working plugin -- answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scratch that, the problem is caused by the keyup() event handler not being invoked, but that is not caused by your e.preventDefault call as I removed them and it still has the same issues.

Figured it out -- you can't alert in the callbacks.  This breaks the event chain.  If you remove the alerts and instead do notifications to the user via HTML then all is well.

Comment: I think your on to something. Its definitely something to do with the active keys not clearing.

Comment: Yeah, the keyup event handler is not reliably firing.  I'm trying to determine what is preventing it from firing -- reading through a bunch of articles that are saying it's an unreliable event handler...more to come.

Comment: Whats weird is it looks like it only fires the first time, throw an alert or log in there, and no matter what the first key you press is itll alert it 6 times, one time for each function initialized. After that it doesn't fire anymore.

Comment: That is do the the this.each iteration.  For each registration of jkey it is going to run the keyup handler -- although I find that strange.

Comment: Yeah on the api page for keyup looks like people are having the exact same issue, mostly in relation to ctrl keys etc.

Comment: Looks like it's totally fine now! Thanks, i changed my alerts to `console.log`s and it's working. You guys rock!

Comment: If any of you are interested its up on http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey fork it on github at http://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey -- thanks a ton for the help. If you'd like to be mentioned in the thank yous send me your name and URL you want mentioned :D thanks guys!